# Sum of Number of non-decreasing sequences

Tags: combinatorics, summation, contest-math

I know that the number of non-decreasing sequences of length $n$ and numbers in the sequence lying in the range $[l,r]$ is given by $$\binom{n+r-l}{n}$$

What is the formula to find the $$\sum_{n=1}^{N}{\binom{n+r-l}{n}}$$

Comment: Are you asking for a simplification of $\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^N {n+r-l \choose n}$ ?

Comment: @Henry  Yes, exactly

Answer (score 0):

As a hint, if you add $1$ you would then be looking at $$ \displaystyle \sum_{n=0}^N {n+r-l \choose n}$$ and it is worth looking at this for small values of $N$ and $r-l$ to spot a pattern related to Pascal's triangle.

It will give you the result to your original question of $$ \displaystyle {N+r-l+1 \choose N} -1.$$